# Use "npm start" as command to forever in .sh script

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, forever

I have a `.sh` script in my `/etc/init-d/forever` to configure how `forever` starts and stops my Node.js app.

I wanted to start `forever` with the command `npm start`, so I can trigger my scripts from there. Is this possible?

I tried

```
sudo forever start --sourceDir /home/my-app -c npm start
```

but its gets wrong interpreted...

> info:    Forever processing file: start
>   error:   Cannot start forever
>   error:   script /root/start does not exist.

My script so far is:

```
NAME=nodeapp
SOUREC_DIR=/home/nodeapp        
COMMAND="npm start"
SOURCE_NAME=index.js
USER=root
NODE_ENVIROMENT=production

pidfile=/var/run/$NAME.pid
logfile=/var/log/$NAME.log
forever=forever

start() {
    export NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENVIROMENT
    echo "Starting $NAME node instance : "

    touch $logfile
    chown $USER $logfile

    touch $pidfile
    chown $USER $pidfile

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
    sudo -H -u $USER $forever start --pidFile $pidfile -l $logfile -a --sourceDir $SOUREC_DIR -c $COMMAND

    RETVAL=$?
}
```

Comment: It's possible you need the path you your app dir after `"npm start"`, but not sure, check: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/540

Comment: @AntonioVal I had already seen and failed with that solution. But found now how to do it! Thank you for looking onto this also!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found the answer.
Both `--sourceDir` and the path parameter after the `"npm start"`command where necessary:

```
sudo forever --sourceDir /home/my-app -c "npm start" /
```

Comment: Log won't be written in the forever log. It will directly write to the console.

Answer (score 6):

The below command run the forever command in the background with logs in forever.

```
forever start -c "ng serve " ./
```

Note the `./`

Then you can

```
forever list
```

And will be able to see the status and the location of the log file.

```
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command                                                            script forever pid   id logfile                          uptime        
data:    [0] wOj1 ng serve                                              29500   24978    /home/user/.forever/wOj1.log 0:0:25:23.326
```